# Access <AnonymousType> fields

Tags: c#

I have an `AnonymousType` object that contacts two fields with their values. How can I access the value of these fields?

Ex: 
SourceTypeObject `{ Source_Type_Id = 1, Source_Type_Name = "bibliography" }`

I need to do something like : `SourceTypeObject.Source_Type_Id`

Is that possible?

EDIT:

Here's what I get if I tried to access the property directly:
[image]

Comment: Assuming `SourceTypeObject` is the object itself, I don't see why not.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it's fields?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the exact purpose of anonymous types.  The only thing that might prevent you from doing so is if you passed the anonymous type around as a parameter with type "object".  This would hide information about the anonymous type, and it would look like just any old object then.

The only recourse if this is the case is to use reflection, which is slow and awkward.  Anonymous types are a meant to be a very "local" phenomenon, and if you find yourself wanting to use them elsewhere in the program, it's worth the time to promote it to a real type.

EDIT: In response to the image you posted, assuming the array is declared locally just outside of view, try to replace the `object SourceTypeObject` with `var SourceTypeObject`.  This allows it to infer the anonymous type instead of being *told* that it's an `object`.